# Timeout vs no response from server, how can I separate these?

Tags: http, tcp, timeout, response, httpwebresponse

### This question is regarding a bot of mine which's primary focus is scraping.

The path is mapped out correctly and it does what it needs to do.
Rate limits are tested and I am certain this is not a factor, if it was and where it was we received actual responses.

However, the webpage(s) I am trying to scrape seem to have build in a kind of weird/ unfamiliar security manner, something that I haven't came across before. And here I am wondering, how it's executed and how I deal with it appropriately.

While the scraper/bot is doing it's thing, sending requests getting responses, at random times it will encounter this what I suspect is a security measure. There are simply no responses back from the server, not a 4xx error or any at all.

At first sight the proxies just appear dead, but that's not it, because they are not. The proxies work just fine, and manually I can just browse the page on them, no issues here.

The server just stops giving responses.

Now to find a workaround for this, I would need to be able to tell the difference between a timeout (for my proxies) and a no response. They appear the same, but are not.

Does anyone have insight on this problem, maybe there is a genius way to separate those that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

> Now to find a workaround for this, I would need to be able to tell the difference between a timeout (for my proxies) and a no response. They appear the same, but are not.

A timeout is if the server does not respond within a specific time. No response means, that the server either closes the connection either before the timeout occurs or that it will close the connection after the timeout occurred without sending anything back.

The first case can be easily detected by the connection close before timeout. If you want to detect instead if the server will close the connection without response only after your current timeout then your only option is to extend the timeout. There is nothing in the server which will indicate that the server will close the connection without response at some future time.

And since your only connection is with the proxy there is no real way to detect if the problem is at the proxy or the server. Your only hope might be to set your timeout waiting for the proxy larger then the timeout the proxy has waiting for the server. This way you'll maybe get a response from the proxy indicating that the connection to the server timed out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however the problem is that the server does not send a close. And we are looking for a more reliable way than extending timeout.

Comment: No response causing a timeout has nothing to do with a close. There is no close. The connection is still open and nothing was received within the timeout period. A close would be received as an end of stream.

Comment: The  server can only send data or end-of-connection. If it does not send anything you don't know if this "nothing" should be "no data" or "no end-of-connection".

Answer (score 0):

> They appear the same, but are not.

They are the same. There is no difference. A read timeout means that data didn't arrive within the timeout period. For whatever reason. TCP doesn't know, and can't tell you. At the C level, `recv()` returned -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`. That's all the information there is.

What you are asking is tantamount to 'data didn't arrive: where didn't it arrive from?' It's not a meaningful question.

Comment: Is there a way you would recommend looking into, I need to be able to define when proxies are the issue and when the communication with the server has stopped due to "security".

Comment: I've just answered that. TCP doesn't know and can't tell you. All it knows is that data didn't arrive. Why exactly would proxies be the issue?

Comment: proxies aren't the issue, the timeout is. But since proxies aren't 100% reliable I use a timeout for them, if it times out it switches proxy. The problem now is that the random timeouts the webpages give are tricking the code into thinking it's a bad proxy or account.

Comment: So proxies aren't the issue but they are? This isn't making sense. If you get a timeout you should use a retry strategy if appropriate. Period.

Comment: I understand, I wish I could explain it more professionally to you. We have tried a lot of retry strategies, these are; (random) delays, restarting it's function X amount of times before switching accounts/proxies/both, cooling downs. Though I think I am trying the wrong things, I was wondering if you or someone else could share input on what I should try besides the things I just noted.